# How to save an ArcGIS query result as a geoJSON file with linux wget command?

Tags: geojson, wget, arcgis

I'm having some issues saving the results of a query from an ArcGIS service in geoJSON format using `wget`. I can get the desired result if I use the query functionality from the ArcGIS service, but when I use `wget` to perform the operation, what I get is an html document saved in a geoJSON file. This is the `wget` command I run:

`wget -O query_accidents.geojson https://sig.simur.gov.co/arcgis/rest/services/Accidentalidad/WSAcidentalidad_Publico/FeatureServer/0/query?where=ANO_OCURRENCIA_ACC+%3E%3D+2015&objectIds=&time=&geometry=&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&inSR=&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&distance=&units=esriSRUnit_Foot&relationParam=&outFields=*&returnGeometry=true&maxAllowableOffset=&geometryPrecision=&outSR=&havingClause=&gdbVersion=&historicMoment=&returnDistinctValues=false&returnIdsOnly=false&returnCountOnly=false&returnExtentOnly=false&orderByFields=&groupByFieldsForStatistics=&outStatistics=&returnZ=false&returnM=false&multipatchOption=xyFootprint&resultOffset=&resultRecordCount=&returnTrueCurves=false&returnExceededLimitFeatures=false&quantizationParameters=&returnCentroid=false&timeReferenceUnknownClient=false&sqlFormat=none&resultType=&featureEncoding=esriDefault&datumTransformation=&f=geojson`

The address above is generated by the ArcGIS service for a query where I simply filter using the the Where field (`Where: column >= value`), select all columns (`Out Fields: *`), return the Geometry (`Return Geometry: True`) and choose geoJSON as the format (`Format: GeoJSON`). I do nothing with the rest of the fields from the query functionality.

Not sure if relevant, but I'm using an Ubuntu terminal environment in WSL.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: replace `wget` with `wget --debug` in your command. Run it. Then try to read the output and figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: Thanks @pii_ke for your suggestion. I didn't see anything in the debug that could help me a great deal. I tried with a combination of `wget`, `curl` and the **tika-app**. Although I made some progress, I realized I wasn't getting all the columns I needed. I found a website that explains [how to extract data from a map service using python](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000019645), which could be a nice solution since I'm developing the application in python.